# The repository 'http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: ubuntu

When updating, I'm getting these errors:

```
E: The repository 'http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Are you trying to install Oracle JDK 6?

Answer (score 1):

If you trust this repository, then you can add it to you trusted repositories list, by using the method described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53800051/repository-does-not-have-a-release-file-error

That is by adding `trusted=yes` after `deb` in the repository line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. If you administer this repository, then make sure to include the Release file. For further information have a look at here: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format#A.22Release.22_files